# Equipped weapons of Wizards and their Durability

Tags: diablo-iii

For the very first time I am playing a game of the Diablo series and I started as a wizard.

- In the beginning I had equipped a normal wand and I found some swords and bows however I do not understand whether and why (or why not) my default magic attacks have increased damage or not based on the equipped weapon.
- Another noticeable point is that for example my equipped shield always has the same durability value which isn't decreasing. I expected my items to decrease this value while using them or am I misunderstanding something?

Could you please give me some short explanation on these topics?

Comment: The first question is a duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66609/does-the-dps-of-a-weapon-affect-a-wizards-primary-attack-damage). You might want to edit to focus on the durability question. And in general, try to ask one question per question. :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I got my answer so fast, hope nobody will punish me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Durability does not decrease if you're below level 10, which is why you see a constant durability value. As soon as you reach level 10, durability starts getting degraded with use (it is also lowered if you die).

Regarding damage, see [this related question (and its answers)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63708/how-does-my-choice-of-weapon-matter).