# Melee weapon usage by wizard

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Playing by Wizard sometime I do left-click on the opponent and instead of casting the spell my wizard makes a hit by melee weapon.

**Question 1**: Is there any way to disable that?

Sometime I don't have enough mana to cast a spell. If I do right-click action on opponent who is close to my hero, then it looks like the hero also makes a hit by melee weapon...

**Question 2**: Is there any way to configure the action ocurred on right click if there are no enough mana to cast the spell?

Sometimes in case when I get a cool wand that puts a solid amount of damage in melee mode I don't want my wizard to cast a spell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a mouse button to a regular attack?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63413/how-do-i-set-a-mouse-button-to-a-regular-attack) As well as related to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66609/does-the-dps-of-a-weapon-affect-a-wizards-primary-attack-damage

Comment: Q3 is a duplicate.  Q1 and Q2 aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wizard will default to using their weapon if you are out of arcane power and attempt to use a left- or right-click bound skill that requires arcane power (i.e. not a Signature Spell).  If you have a melee weapon equipped, your wizard will then run towards them to attack.  If you have a wand, your wizard will shoot at the enemy.

Q1) This sounds like a bug, unless you have a spell bound to your left click that requires arcane power.  I haven't seen this behaviour.

Q2) There is no way to change the "out of arcane power" behaviour of using your equipped weapon.  You can hold down the Shift key to avoid running into melee an enemy if you are wielding a melee weapon but that only mitigates the behaviour, it does not change it.

Q3) You can bind the default attack to a left or right mouse button by removing that button's binding to any other skill ([How do I set a mouse button to a regular attack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63413/how-do-i-set-a-mouse-button-to-a-regular-attack)).